# Entity Relational Model Design and Query Method

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy, entity-relationship

**Current Design:**
Users and Groups: [Many-to-Many Table](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) 
Tools: SQLAlchemy 1.0.9, Python 2.7, Pyramid

**The two questions I pose to you**:

1. I am uncertain if I should have the `group` attribute under `User` *or* the `user` attribute under `Group`. This is a MANY-TO-MANY relationship; with a third table that relates the two different classes.
2. SQLAlchemy has a lot of great examples discussing `.join`s, but I'm finding the task is difficult with this DB design for querying based on the selected username. (see below)

I have designed a SQLAlchemy database and am trying to implement best practices for retrieving data from my table while eliminating redundancy. With that said, I also want this to be an effective design so that when I build a `group_finder` function using [Pyramid's Authorization and Authentication System](http://michael.merickel.org/projects/pyramid_auth_demo/group_security.html), so that I have no issue.

I am using a `CRUD` methodology. As of right now: To add a `user` to a `Group`, I `update_group_add_user(...)` to add a user or `update_group_remove_users(...)` to remove a user.

---

*base.py*

**Commented out `groups` and added `users` to `class Group`**

```
association_table = Table('group_user_link', Base.metadata,
    Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id')),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = Column(String(300))
    password = Column(String(300), nullable=False)

    #groups = relationship('Group', secondary='group_user_link', backref='users') 

    def __init__(self, username, password, firstname, lastname, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = hashlib.sha224(password).hexdigest()
        self.email = email
        #self._groups = groups

    def __repr__(self): # code

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_name = Column(String(50), unique=True)

    users = relationship('User', secondary='group_user_link', backref='groups')

    def __init__(self, group_name, user=None):
        if user is None: user = []
        self.group_name = group_name
        self._user = user # to group_add_user and group_remove_user

    def __repr__(self): # code
```

Query method (using CRUD): 
This prints out ALL the relationships in tuples in a list. I want to only print out (and return) only the user being entered.

```
def retrieve_user_bygroup(self, username):
    query= self.session.query(User, Group).join(association).\
    filter(User.id == Group.id).\
    order_by(User.id).all()
    print "retrieve user by group:",  query
    return query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered two similarly asked questions that clarified the use of `backref`, `.join`, and `.query` in **SQLAlchemy**. This helped clarify how the backref line in `users = relationship('User', secondary='group_user_link', backref='groups')` made `groups` accessible through `User` when later querying with a `.join` and  `.filter` (shown at the bottom).

[Discussing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211070/sqlalchemy-basic-question/2256154#2256154) the purpose of `backref`:

> backref means a 'poster' attribute will be added to UserPost. Actually
>   I'd probably call that 'user'. But the point is that 'relation()'
>   knows how to join between those two tables because of the previously
>   defined ForeignKey.

[Discussing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044309/sqlalchemy-how-to-join-several-tables-by-one-query) `.join` and `.query`:

> `.join` [works] according [to] the relations, and yields 3-tuples. The arguments to
>   the `query()` call are essentially the select list in sqlalchemy.

I also found this [Stacks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900387/how-to-query-for-all-groups-of-type-foo-that-contain-user-x-many-to-many-tab/24900837#24900837) to be helpful with using `.any()`

```
def retrieve_group_byuser(self, username):
    # retrieves group by username
    query = self.session.query(Group).\
    filter(Group.users.any(User.username == username)).all()
    print "retrieved by username:", query
    return query
```

And I removed `groups` from `User` which now looks like this:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(15), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = Column(String(300))
    password = Column(String(300), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password, firstname, lastname, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = hashlib.sha224(password).hexdigest()
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self): 
        # code
```

Answer (score -1):

1. I would say `group` should contain [say a `set` of] `users` in it. Not the other way round.

Now, you might have a need to know the group given the user, if you want to cache this mapping in memory (instead of getting it from DB) then I would recommend NOT to create a circular dependency between `group` and `user` classes. Instead promote the that dependency to a third class, which just defines the relation between group and users.

E.g.

```
class user:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class group:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class user_group_relation:
    def get_users(self, grp_name):
        # could get it from an internal map (like return g2u_mapping[grp_name]) or 
        # run a query on some DB table..
        pass

    def get_group(self, usr_name):
        # could get it from an internal map or run a query on some DB table..
        pass

    # group to user mapping
    u2g_mapping = {user('user1'): group('group1'), user('user2'): group('group1')}
    g2u_mapping = {group('group1'): [user('user1'), user('user2')]}
```

2. if this is e.g. a representation of normal user authentication mechanism then only users have passwords, groups don't. Groups just represent a way to organizing things. Hence the password field (and any related functionality should remain in user and not promoted to base.

Comment: Yes, Group is just a means of organizing the Users (e.g. admin, editor, general_user). YES, I do need to query user with group (as you show in the relation) for a `group_finder` function in `Pyramid` down the road. I think since I am already following `CRUD` methods...I will add a `retrieve_user_group` and `retrieve_group_user` method to resolve the issue I am having with finding user by group and etc.

Comment: The many-to-many table with SQLAlchemy does the relationship between the two classes justice by relating the two. Just wanted to make sure my code was not redundant.

Comment: @thesayhey Okay.. Just want to underline that how it's implemented is less imp than the relationships between classes. Circular dependencies are BAD news. Probably worse news in C++ or such where you have to compile code, but bad none the less.